# Loading Symfony FormBuilder `choices` from doctrine query

Tags: arrays, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to generate a form element with the below code. The <kbd>products</kbd> array that I'm trying to feed in contains all unique values of my <kbd>Product</kbd> entity.

My <kbd>Product</kbd> and  <kbd>Order</kbd> entities have a Many-to-Many relationship setup in Doctrine:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;

class DefaultController extends FOSRestController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/newOrder", name="new_order")
     */
    public function newOrderAction(Request $request)
    {
        $order = new Order();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $products = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
            ->findAllOrderedByName();

        $form = $this->CreateFormBuilder($order)
            ->add('products','choice', array(
                    'choices' => $products,
                'multiple' => true,
            ))
            ->add('Save','submit',array('label'=>'Update Order'))
            ->getForm();
    }
}
```

However, I don't see why the form I'm getting returned shows `product#2` for each option as well as generating the `<optgroup>` label which is making the dropdown menu a bit clunky.

```
<select id="form_products" name="form[products]">
    <optgroup label="0">
        <option value="id" >Product#2</option></optgroup>
    <optgroup label="1">
        <option value="id" >Product#2</option></optgroup>
</select>
```

The function I have in my product repository is:

```
public function findAllOrderedByName()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p.description FROM AppBundle:Product p ORDER BY p.description ASC'
        )
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use 'choice' form field but 'entity' one. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: And use 'query_builder' option of entity form field to get products ordered by description

Comment: @Viktor77 - Wish I could have accepted that comment as an answer as I'm up and running again :-) Thanks

Comment: Hi @Bendy, I'm gonna post it as an answer so you can accept it, it could be useful for more people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use 'choice' form field but 'entity' one and use 'query_builder' option of entity form field to get products ordered by description.